# python simple example - ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

When I execute this python code, I got an error message : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

What's the problem? could you help me?

```
a=np.array([1,3,5,7,9], dtype=int)
c=np.array([3,4,7,8,9], dtype=int)
b=np.zeros(len(a))

for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i]= np.where(a == int(c[i]))
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you look at the result the `where` function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in `b[i]= np.where(a == int(c[i]))`this returns an array that only contains a single element in your example. However, v is also one dimensional and you have to assign scalars not arrays. If you are sure that the search only return 1 element, you can do `b[i]= np.where(a == int(c[i]))[0]`

Comment: Thank you for replying. It was what I want. Firstly, I broke the ```b[i]= np.where(a == int(c[i]))[0]``` into ```d=np.where(a == int(c[i]))``` and ```b[i]=d```, then It worked. Anyway, thank you , again!

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try to append it to b instead of replacing the value?

```
     B.append(np.where( a == c[i]))
```

Also try using if conditions inside the for loop :)

Comment: I also recommend this solution, but you should state that `b` is a now a list rather than an array

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your array `b`. Since it is an array, it is not as flexible as a list. Since your `np.where` statement sometimes returns an empty array or even possibly an array with more scalars in it, it is a bit problematic.
You will be better of to define `b` as a list:

```py
a=np.array([1,3,5,7,9], dtype=int)
c=np.array([3,4,7,8,9], dtype=int)
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
     b.append(np.where(a==c[i])[0])

print(b)

[array([1]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([3]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([4])]
```

Only if you are entirely certain that your `np.where` statement will return one and only one scalar, you can use the solution of @Simon Hawe.

Do note that this returns the indexes of `a` where the statement is True! If you want the value itself, the code becomes

```py
a=np.array([1,3,5,7,9], dtype=int)
c=np.array([3,4,7,8,9], dtype=int)
b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(a[np.where(a==c[i])])

print(b)

[array([3]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([7]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([9])]
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. It is not exactly what I want, but It will be helpful to me. Thank you so much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I should just vote to close this since you did not provide enough debugging information, especially not the full **traceback**.

But let's look at what you are doing.  On the first iteration:

```
In [342]: a==c[0]
Out[342]: array([False,  True, False, False, False])
In [343]: np.where(a==c[0])
Out[343]: (array([1]),)
```

Pay attention to what `where` produced.  It's a **tuple**, not a single number (even though it only found on `True`).  If that isn't clear, **read** the docs.

When we try to assign that value to the an element of the `b` array (which has `float` dtype):

```
In [344]: b[0] = np.where(a==c[0])
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-344-b205dc5b1048>", line 1, in <module>
    b[0] = np.where(a==c[0])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Did you get that full message?  If so, why did you just quote the last line?

While it's possible to extract that `[1]` from the `where` tuple, for other iterations, the result may be empty - no match!

```
In [346]: np.where(a==c[1])
Out[346]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
In [347]: np.where(a==c[2])
Out[347]: (array([3]),)
In [348]: np.where(a==c[3])
Out[348]: (array([], dtype=int64),)
```

It is possible to collect the results of these `where` in a list, but why?

```
In [349]: [np.nonzero(a==c[i])[0] for i in range(5)]
Out[349]: 
[array([1]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([3]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([4])]
```

Comment: ```---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-606-7b50beb044f5> in <module>()
     14 
     15 for i in range(len(a)):
---> 16     b[i]= np.where(a == int(c[i]))

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.```

Comment: Above is the whole error message that I got. And Thank you for replying. It really helped me.